# Laravel 5 - Error updating with Form Facade

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-facade

Im trying to update the user object using a form facade in laravel, after submiting i get the error:

```
ErrorException in Grammar.php line 102:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, 
string given, called in 
C:\Laravel Projects\ExpenseTool\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 105 and defined
```

My request:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class UserRequest extends Request {

/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'email'
    ];
}

}
```

My HomeController index:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('Expenses.home', compact( 'user'));
}
```

My form in view Expenses.home:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PUT', 'action' => ['HomeController@update', $user->id]]) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Name', 'Name:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Email', 'Email:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

my route:

```
Route::resource('home', 'HomeController',  ['only' => ['update']]);
```

my HomeController@update:

```
public function update($id, UserRequest $request)
{
    $loggedUser = Auth::user();

    $userDB = User::get($id);

    $username = $request->input('name');

    $userDB->name = $username;

    $userDB->update();

    return redirect('home');
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change

`public function update($id, UserRequest $request)
{
    $loggedUser = Auth::user();

```
// you are cool to use findOrFail
$userDB = User::find($id);

$username = $request->input('name');

$userDB->name = $username;

$userDB->update();

return redirect('home');
```

}`

your error is causes by the `get()` method require you to pass an array of columns you would like to retrieves from database